# Set TableView Cell image from AFNetworking download

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to download rss feed image set to table view. Following is the code I'm using.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableview *)tableView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *wallpaperLink = [af setThumbString:[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"wallpaper"]];

    //AfNetwork Download
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wallpaperLink]]];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       //Set Cell Image from response
       cell.imageView.image = responseObject;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
    }];
    [requestOperation start];

    return cell;
}
```

But when I go through some tutorials I realise that this is not the way to download asynchronous images with AFNetworking. Can someone tell me for my code, how to download & add the `responseobject` to `cell.imageView.image` ???

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I do it that way to avoid memory leaks:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:url..."];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_placeholder"];

__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                      placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                   weakCell.imageView.image = image;
                                   [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                               } failure:nil];
```

It works fine with AFNetworking 2.

As @Greg suggest in a comment:
You have to add #import `"UIImageView+AFNetworking.h".`

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:' This Error comes to me

Comment: You have to add #import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h".

Answer (score 5):

If you are using AFNetworking, why not use the UIImageView+AFNetworking category? Just import UIImageView+AFNetworking.h and use this method:

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

**Edit: Don't forget to call `setNeedsLayout` on the cell after you set the image!**

Comment: I can't add UIImageView+AFNetworking.h. UIImageView+AFNetworking.h file not found error there

Comment: If you cloned a copy of the AFNetworking repository (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) you will find that class and other UIKit categories in the "UIKit+AFNetworking" folder. Let me know if you need help finding it. You just need to drag "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h" into your project.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing asynchronous image downloading, you can't get the result image on `UITableViewCell` immediately. So, You should download the images and show them using array of downloaded image as per `tableView` `indexPath`.

Please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/lazytableimages/introduction/intro.html) to download image using lazy-loading and display it in `UITableViewCell`.

Thanks!